# PHP5. Оператор switch

Tags: php

Что выведет на печать оператор switch при выполнении кода:

```
$name = array("Михаил","Иван","Петр");
switch (true) {
case 0: echo $name[0] . " чинит машину"; break;
case 1: echo $name[1] . " копает картофель"; break;
case 2: echo $name[2] . " тратит деньги"; break;
default: echo "Все отдыхают!";
}
```

не понимаю

Comment: А, запустить код на выполнение и посмотреть не пробовали?

Comment: Ну или почитать справку по значениям предопределённых констант и неявным преобразованиям.

Comment: Справки какие-то читать, код запускать. Кому это надо.

Answer (score 1):

Выводом будет: Иван копает картофель.

Так как `true` приравнивается к 1, и когда дойдет до `case 1` выолнится эта часть

Comment: Формулировка не совсем верная. 1 приравнивается к true, а не наоборот, так же как и 2) А 0 приравнивается к false

Answer (score -1):

Вывод будет: `Иван копает картофель.`

Comment: Можешь описать еще как это работает, чтоб в ответе появилась хоть какая-то ценность?

Comment: @РашенБеар, вопрос не об этом же.